# Get Text with Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I need to extract text Paul Robert this html and print to the console using the Java WebDriver and selenium .

The code below extracts all text Div , even the text " Quit".

```
<div role="alert" class="alert success" id="control_gen_3">
 <p>
 <strong>Invite to <a href="">Paul Robert</a>.</strong></p>
 <button class="dismiss" id="global-error-dismiss">Quit</button>
 </div>
```

Code Selenium:

```
String pessoa = driver.findElement(By.id("control_gen_3")).getText();               
System.out.println(pessoa );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String pessoa = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='control_gen_3']//a")).getText();               
System.out.println(pessoa );
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 1):

```
String pessoa = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#control_gen_3 a")).getText();               
System.out.println(pessoa);
```

This means you fetch the element with id `control_gen_3` and look for an `a` within that element.